# Can we get a migration path to SuperUser?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, migration-path-request

I don't know if this is just observation bias, but it seems like we've had a number of questions recently that should be migrated to SuperUser.  This migration path, by far, would be the most common for us other than the simple migrate to meta.  Can we get this migration path added to our close box?

Comment: +1, I was wondering why we didn't have that any more.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: all the minecraft setup questions are more like "how can i get java libs to work?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/159728/migrations-from-arqade-to-su) against our migrated posts, here's what I came up with:

- We've migrated a total of 36 posts to SU over the life of our site
- Two have been rejected.
- We migrated nine last year.  One of which was rejected.

From that, I don't believe we have enough migration traffic to really justify a migration path.

Granted, some users post their question here, we refer them to SU, and they re-post it there.  I am looking to see how I can match that up, but I'm not optimistic on any real results.

Of course, it could also be we don't migrate bad questions, and the user would rather just repost than fix it up to be a migration candidate.  But [even there](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/159729/closed-questions-referred-to-su), I'm not seeing a ton of questions referred to SU.  I got a total of 31 rows where a closed question has a comment mentioning SuperUser, and there's several that have more than one comment that mention SU.

Comment: There has been a few questions where I commented to the effect of "this would be better suited to Super User, flagging for migration" and flagged as such, and the user reposted it there before my flag was actioned by mods, the most recent being [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145982/options-to-increase-ping) (10k only) which was reposted to SU [here](http://superuser.com/questions/687831/options-to-increase-ping-latency)

Comment: My point being that I'd be interested in seeing the metric from the other side, i.e. setup the migration path, live with it for 6 months - 1 year, and evaluate whether to keep it afterward

Comment: @Robotnik I think that question could be a good fit for either site, but the scopes would be different. SU can give a technical answer (which is what's happening) while Arqade could tend to the specifics of the game (i.e. if there were tools or configurations inside the game that enabled the process).

Comment: Damn you and your science making a compelling argument.  Still, I think it's worth while to streamline these cases, regardless of the rarity that they occur.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - I don't really consider messing with packet latency/ping times a game-specific function - most games would only need to access the TCP/IP layer at best for their networking functions, whereas if you're accessing individual packets to simulate bad connection/slow internet you're operating at a much lower level.. Sure, games add stuff like wide hitboxes/lag compensation, but that's done with calculations and logic/prediction, it doesn't touch the networking side at all.

Comment: @Robotnik It occurred to me, that Data.SE doesn't allow cross-site queries.  So I can't really figure out a reasonable way of comparing cross posted questions, short of using massive filtering through excel or something.

Comment: @Robotnik My understanding is that SE has done pretty much what you suggest for other sites, and ended up with the current method (only add migration paths if there is already a large number of migrations) because you end up with a lot of bad migrations otherwise.  It's possible that Gaming could buck the trend and send a lot of good stuff to SU, but I wouldn't put money on it.

Comment: @MatthewRead - Every site is different though, Gaming has one of the strictest SE communities that I've seen - I think if we laid down the rules clearly we could minimize the potential damage caused. Of course if youre right, and SE won't even give the request time of day because "it didnt work well on other sites" then the situation is moot, but I still think its worth a shot.

Comment: @Robotnik I'm pretty sure they won't consider it -- Android was around the same numbers when they refused us IIRC -- but if you think it's worth trying for I certainly wouldn't stop you.  The problem is not usually with the established Meta users, but all the other 3k+ rep folks.

Comment: @MatthewRead - Another situation where the user was redirected to SuperUser instead of migrating as such: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151384/port-forwarding-different-ports-in-router-log