# What happened to the option to move questions to a different Stack in vote to close?

Tags: support, migration

There used to be an option for vote to close that would allow us to migrate questions to other Stack sites. I'm currently referencing this question [How do you disable keyboard inputs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/369349/how-do-you-disable-keyboard-inputs).

It would be better suited over at superuser, but the only option I see is to move the question to this meta.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about this? [This (admittedly, six years old) answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8207/168837) indicates there wasn't a migration path back then, and there was no real need for it either.

Comment: @Glorfindel If I recall correctly, we did have migration paths to a couple other sites years ago, but I believe they went away around 2013 or so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Migration paths to outside sites have been closed [since at least 2014](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8206). From what I understand, migration was mostly used poorly, so the tool was taken away from 3k users.

While migration paths outside meta aren't there for regular users, moderators can migrate questions to other sites. If you think a question should be migrated, please flag it for moderator attention and we'll take a look. In this particular case, I've gone ahead and performed the migration.

Comment: Shows how much I've used that feature if it was removed since 2014 :P Admittedly I only recently started actively being a part of this stack again in the past few months.